# How can I get EBS volume type with python boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I started writing simple nagios check in python to monitor "Burst Balance" on EBS gp2 volumes. I'd like to skip checking volumes with Provisioned IOPS (io1)

I can get this information with `aws ec2 describe-volumes`.

How can I check volume type with boto in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `boto3` [`describe_volumes()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_volumes) call returns the volume type:

```
'VolumeType': 'standard'|'io1'|'gp2'|'sc1'|'st1'
```

I couldn't find an equivalent in `boto`, but it's probably time to move across to `boto3`. If desired, you can use both of them in the same application, simply `import boto3` and use it in parallel.